# missing ) after for-loop control - Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I try to make a Calculator for Math exercices like : `x^2+2(2x+3)+3x`
But atm I get always `missing ) after for-loop control`
In the code below, I try to find the closest operator (`+` or `-`) to the next `(`.

Maybe I just failed with two `for()` in one, but never saw a problem there.

```
for (var i = 0; i < indexAuf.length; i++;) {
  // Which operator is the closest to the "(" \\
  var maxPlus = 0;
  var maxMinus = 0;

  for (var j = 0; j < indexPlus; j++;) {
    if (indexPlus[j] < indexAuf[i]) {
      if (indexPlus[j] > maxPlus) {
        indexPlusMax = indexPlus[j]
        indexPlusMaxj = j
      }
    }
  }

  for (var l = 0; l < indexMinus; l++;) {
    if (indexPlus[l] < indexAuf[i]) {
      if (indexMinus[l] > maxMinus) {
        indexMinusMax = indexPlus[l]
        indexMinusMaxl = i
      }
    }
  }

  if (indexMinusMaxl > indexPlusMaxj) {
    alert("indexMinusMaxl" + indexMinusMaxl);
  } else {
    alert("indexPlusMaxj" + indexPlusMaxj);
  }

} else {
  return;
}
```

If you´ve some ideas how to improve the code. I've posted the complete code @Pasbin

http://pastebin.com/VdWeMqBx

Thanks.

Comment: The last semicolon in your loops, after incrementing the counter variable, is wrong – remove it.

Comment: I rolled back your edit - please do NOT change your question to reflect the answer :) - this renders any answers on the page irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error message implies the missing ')' before the ';':

```
for (var i = 0; i < indexAuf.length; i++;) { }
```

correct is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < indexAuf.length; i++) { }
```

Comment: Now it works, thanks. But now it won't go into the next two for loops.

Comment: @Quatzel because `j < indexPlus` is not the same as `j < indexPlus.length`

Comment: I guess, I should stop for today, I already miss the smallest mistakes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last semicolon in `for (var i = 0; i < indexAuf.length; i++;){/*...*/}`

The `for` loop syntax rule inside the compiler is something like this:

```
 for PARENTHESIS STATEMENT SEMICOLON EXPRESSION SEMICOLON STATEMENT PARENTHESIS BLOCK
```

Another semicolon in the end would lead to syntax error.